# MSTest launches v4.0 version of QTAgent for .NET v4.5.2 test Assembly

Tags: .net, mstest

If I build a test assembly with target framework v4.5 and run MSTest on it, it will launch an instance of QTAgent32.exe. However, if I set the target framework to v4.5.2 and run MSTest it will instead launch an instance of QTAgent32_40.exe.

Why is this? How can I make MSTest.exe pick the correct QTAgent (QTAgent32.exe in this case)? What determines which QTAgent is started?

Edit: This happens both using the VS2013 and VS2015 versions of MSTest/QTAgent.

Comment: Well, it would certainly be best to avoid picking a target version that VS2013 does not know anything about.  You'll need to explain why you think it is necessary to target 4.5.2

Comment: The target version 4.5.2 is chosen in VS2013 (When upgrading the from 4.5 we had to install the 4.5.2 targeting pack in order to pick that target).
Is the issue that since VS213 ships with support for 4.5.1 max, then tooling like MsTest is not ready to handle assemblies built for higher targets? The test work perfectly fine if I force it to use the v4.5 QTAgent, e.g. by just copying it over the 4.0 exe as a hack...
The application needs to be retargeted against 4.5.2 because references have done so (And while it's possible to run it anyway I really don't want to...)

Comment: I have access to the VS2015 toolchain as well. Can't switch VS entirely just yet for various reasons but should perhaps use the 2015 MSTest tools for the v4.5.2 assemblies built from 2013?

Comment: @HansPassant Doing this entirely on 4.6.1/VS2015 doesn't matter. The VS2015 mstest also launches QTAgent32_40.exe in case the test assembly targets 4.5.2.

Comment: Meh, VS2015 has a new test runner, it probably still uses QTAgent for legacy projects.